# Netbeans: generate DTD for XML

Tags: xml, plugins, netbeans, dtd

Is there any plugin solution to Netbeans to create DTD from XML files 
(and/or validating XML by DTD) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a DTD in NetBeans right-click on an XML file in the Files or Project view and select 'Generate DTD...' This will generate a DTD for the selected XML file. I don't know a way to generate for multiple XML files. You will need to merge (some of the) generated DTD files into one.

Answer (score 2):

You can add DTD's to Netbeans via the `Tools` --> `DTDs and XML Schemas` dialog, like explained [in this blog](http://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/registering-local-dtds-or-xml-schemas-with-netbeans/).

I haven't seen a plugin that (re)creates a DTD from XML sample data for Netbeans yet, I always used [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) for that kind of work.  But XMLSpy is [not free](https://shop.altova.com/pricelist.asp)...

Comment: because adding DTD after every recreation is not nice task, and Altova XMLSpy is only Windows tool, this is not good option. I search for multiplatform solution and easy on-the-fly generating DTD... really no chance?

Comment: I feel your pain :-) but it's the only one I have experience with, and it's a pretty good tool. But even in XMLSpy reverse engineering schema/DTD sounded a lot more useful than it was in reality, because especially with schema a lot of detail and intention got lost in translation.  In most cases the reverse engineered version is a good starting point, but not much more than that...